# How can I kill the bonus stage center turret?

Tags: sky-force-2014

The center turret in the bonus stage 1 (They gave it a number but there doesn't seem to be another one. Maybe they'll add another stage later with an update) seems to be the key enemy force to eliminate but I can't find a way to disable it. I searched all the walkthroughs I could find on the net but no one seems to be concentrating on it. Did anyone out there ever find a way to kill it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to kill this center turret on Bonus stage 1. You can't shoot at it, use missiles at it, Bombs, or your laser. It's just one of those things that never dies.

[image]